# Twilio: Can I make OUTBOUND Conference Calls?

Tags: twilio, conference

The Twilio markup language clearly defines how INCOMING calls can be joined to a common conference room.

But I want to dial several calls simultaneously and join those.  If I use the "dial" verb within the markup language, I get several *consecutive* calls, but I'd like them in parallel.

The basic operation of my application is to receive a call from the conference leader and actively connect all parties to the conference.

Answer (score 4):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

This is very easy to achieve using the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) instead of using the TwiML verb `dial` to call each attendee. First of all, you put the conference leader into the conference room:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>my room</Conference>
  </Dial>
<Response>
```

(Note that you may want hold music, or other instructions etc..)

Next, you use the REST API and dial in the other participants. There is a quick start to help you get going with outbound calls, [this one is in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest) but you can use the language switcher on the page for whatever your need. Then you can just use the URL for the above TwiML to connect those calls to the same conference room. You can also use other TwiML documents, the important factor here is that `Conference` room name matches. Then everyone will be on the same call.

[Helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) are available in Ruby, PHP, Python, C#, Java and Node to help you with the REST API.

Hope this help!

Comment: How can you connect an outbound call to a conference?

Comment: I'm not sure to completely understand. Imagine I want a conference call with 2 phones (say `to_number` and `second_to_number`). Do I need to make two "voice call": A first one connecting `twilio_number` to `to_number` and a second one connecting `twilio_number` to `second_to_number`? That's not really clear in the documentation for [conference calls either](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls-python).

Comment: Waaaaaay too late to help, but yes. Last time I looked (forever ago!) you make two outbound calls and conference them into the same room. Exactly as you describe.